# System.IO.PathTooLongException when building Asp.Net Core project

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2005

When I build project with Visual Studio 2016 update 3 Asp.Net Core I receive this error and the build is terminated:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4018 The "FindConfigFiles" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(String path)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(String path)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath, Func`2 filter)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FileHelpers.RecursiveGatherConfigFiles(String directoryPath, String projectPath)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FindConfigFiles.FindConfigFilesOnDisk()
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FindConfigFiles.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() D:\weblFront\frontWeb\src\frontWeb\frontWeb.xproj   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets 156

I do not use any tool etc. Only Gulp. How to fix this problem please.

Comment: Which npm version are you using? (do npm -v in the console)

Comment: npm version is: 4.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a simple error caused by a path (probably in a dependency) being too long for Windows.  You may be able to solve this just by shortening the path to the folder with your code.

e.g. Try moving the project folder

from D:\weblFront\frontWeb\src\frontWeb\frontWeb\

to D:\Code\frontWeb\

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. It works now. I moved the contents of D:\weblFront\frontWeb\src\frontWeb\ to D:\web and it works.

Comment: After a little Googling, it looks like some people have fixed similar issues by purging and re-installing their NPM packages.  Not sure why that would help, but it's easy to try.

Comment: I will give it a try after having some time. I wish I could finish my first Asp.Net Core project asap. I created the first page twice and every time this problem arises. When I moved to a shorter folder name it is fixed. I wish it will not come again.

Comment: It looks like it does not accept any front slash. If I put the contents of the project in d:\web\src it does not accept. Meanwhile, when I put them in d:\webbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb it is ok!!! I think the problem is related to System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths) as described.